# Rails 3 nested routes parameter names different

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-routing

I have a nested resource that looks like this:

```
resources :events
  resources :attendances
    post 'update_email'
  end
end
```

and it shows me routes that look like this (left out most of the standard REST routes for brevity):

```
             event_attendance GET  /events/:event_id/attendances/:id
event_attendance_update_email POST /events/:event_id/attendances/:event_attendance_id/update_email
```

So, why is it that when I add new routes, they have a different id parameter?

Comment: it would be better to write this answer in answers and accept your own answer. Then people would see, that question is already with answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ack, figured this out almost immediately after posting.

The problem is that I didn't specify that it was a route for a member resource:

```
resources :events
  resources :attendances
    member do
      post 'update_email'
    end
  end
end
```

produces what I wanted:

```
event_attendance GET  /events/:event_id/attendances/:id
event_attendance_update_email POST /events/:event_id/attendances/:id/update_email
```